# Playstore stuck on downloading apps, cannot install anything

Tags: google-play-store

I can't install apps. All my phone does is to show the installation progress-bar, but nothing else: it never does download.

I've already rebooted my phone and took my SD card and my battery out. And it still it doesn't work.

I have 4g/LTE data, the device is an Alcatel one touch pop asrto. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the app using Wi-Fi or checking if you have enough storage space for the app.